# JavaFX - imageview node only shows with window resize

Tags: javafx

I'm using JavaFX. When i add an imageview node to the stack pane and then run the application, I can only see the image after manually resizing the window (dragging the edge of the window with my mouse).

It will also show up if i setTranslateX or setTranslateY the image away from its original location. But if I want it to just stay there, I have to manually resize the window to see it. Has anyone encountered this? Is it a bug I just have to deal with?

Thanks

Comment: Have not had this problem. Can you create a short example of the error?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest JDK version 121. I had rendering issues on earlier versions, especially 65